# Bordermatrix without the top row

Tags: matrices, bordermatrix

Is it possible to remove the top row from a `\bordermatrix`? I only need to put indices on the left of the matrix, but even if I don't enter any values, my document creates a blank line above the matrix:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
Some text goes here. Even more text goes here.
$$\Phi = \bordermatrix{&&&&&&&\cr A & 90&85&78&73&73&70&69 \cr B &95&851&77&73&73&68&66}.$$
Some text goes here. Even more text goes here.
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could use `blkarray` instead: `\usepackage{blkarray}` and then `\[
\Phi=
\begin{blockarray}[t]{@{}c(cccccccc)}
B & 95 & 851& 77 & 73 & 73 & 68 & 66
\end{blockarray}
\]`

Comment: Avoid `$$`: see [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)